# Permissions error when trying to install jquery-ui/data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, gridstack

Trying to use React-gridstack on a create-react-app and every time I run the command:

> npm i jquery-ui/data

when it asks me to, I get this error:

````
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/jquery-ui/data.git
npm ERR! Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

That error is telling you that you either don't have permission to access the repository, this might occur if you're attempting to install a package from a private repository, or that the package you are trying to install does not exist.

In your case the latter is most likely the cause, I assume what you actually want is:

```
npm i jquery-ui
```